# How we can get last query on a special table with query text and host name and login name like sql profiler?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How can we get last query on a special table with query text and host name and login name like sql server profiler?

such as this sample -

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Comment: By running a trace? If you didn't have it in place before the query in question, you are not going to find it.

Comment: such as this sample   -SELECT  deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs  
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC

Comment: Don't put code into comments; edit it into your question instead.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Last statement before a connection is closed?  Last statement before?  There are different things you can use, like server trace, extended events, etc., but I'm not totally clear on what you want

Comment: very good  .thank you